# USB Webcam only recognized with delay

Tags: usb, camera

I have an external webcam that I attach to my computer via USB. On my computer I am running KDE Neon 20.3 (based on Ubuntu 20.04) with kernel 5.4.0-54-generic.

When I plug my webcam in, it always takes quite a while (probably ~3-5 minutes) before it is recognized as a webcam (verified by trying to use `guvcview` to access it).

The odd thing though is that it is recognized as an USB device almost immediately. If I execute `lsusb` shortly after having plugged the webcam in, I get

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 013: ID 05a3:9331 ARC International Camera
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

where the "Camera" entry is the one that only appears after having plugged the camera in.

Before the abovementioned period of time though, `guvcview` complains that it can't find a "video device".

Therefore the recognition of the USB device does not seem to be same time at which the system recognizes that a camera was plugged in.

I am now wondering what the cause of this could be and whether there is something that I could try to make my system recognize the camera faster (e.g. by manually executing some command). Does anyone have an idea?

---

Note: Once the camera has been recognized, it works like charm. So it really only is the recognition itself that is odd, not the camera's functionality on Linux.

EDIT: The relevant content from `/var/log/kern.log` after having plugged my camera in:

```
Nov 30 19:31:17 bob kernel: [ 3501.535173] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
Nov 30 19:31:17 bob kernel: [ 3501.684089] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05a3, idProduct=9331, bcdDevice= 1.00
Nov 30 19:31:17 bob kernel: [ 3501.684091] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Nov 30 19:31:17 bob kernel: [ 3501.684091] usb 3-1: Product: HD Web Camera
Nov 30 19:31:17 bob kernel: [ 3501.684092] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Ingenic Semiconductor CO., LTD.
Nov 30 19:31:17 bob kernel: [ 3501.684093] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: Ucamera001
Nov 30 19:31:17 bob kernel: [ 3501.690619] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HD Web Camera (05a3:9331)
Nov 30 19:31:18 bob kernel: [ 3502.215188] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 2 on unit 1: -110 (exp. 1).
Nov 30 19:31:18 bob kernel: [ 3502.320523] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 7 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 1).
Nov 30 19:31:19 bob kernel: [ 3502.951206] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 8 on unit 2: -110 (exp. 1).
Nov 30 19:31:19 bob kernel: [ 3503.463251] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 9 on unit 2: -110 (exp. 1).
Nov 30 19:31:20 bob kernel: [ 3503.975219] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 10 on unit 2: -110 (exp. 1).
Nov 30 19:31:20 bob kernel: [ 3504.487221] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 1 on unit 2: -110 (exp. 1).
Nov 30 19:31:21 bob kernel: [ 3504.999206] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 4 on unit 2: -110 (exp. 1).
Nov 30 19:31:21 bob kernel: [ 3505.511212] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 5 on unit 2: -110 (exp. 1).
Nov 30 19:31:22 bob kernel: [ 3506.023255] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 11 on unit 2: -110 (exp. 1).
Nov 30 19:31:32 bob kernel: [ 3516.203320] uvcvideo: UVC non compliance - GET_DEF(PROBE) not supported. Enabling workaround.
Nov 30 19:31:37 bob kernel: [ 3521.319412] uvcvideo: Failed to query (129) UVC probe control : -110 (exp. 26).
Nov 30 19:31:37 bob kernel: [ 3521.319414] uvcvideo: Failed to initialize the device (-5).
Nov 30 19:32:18 bob kernel: [ 3562.279789] usb 3-1: 3:1: cannot set freq 16000 to ep 0x83
Nov 30 19:32:28 bob kernel: [ 3572.519903] usb 3-1: 6:2: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 6)
Nov 30 19:32:28 bob kernel: [ 3572.520236] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 11
Nov 30 19:32:28 bob kernel: [ 3572.795884] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
Nov 30 19:32:29 bob kernel: [ 3572.944792] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05a3, idProduct=9331, bcdDevice= 1.00
Nov 30 19:32:29 bob kernel: [ 3572.944794] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Nov 30 19:32:29 bob kernel: [ 3572.944795] usb 3-1: Product: HD Web Camera
Nov 30 19:32:29 bob kernel: [ 3572.944796] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Ingenic Semiconductor CO., LTD.
Nov 30 19:32:29 bob kernel: [ 3572.944797] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: Ucamera001
Nov 30 19:32:29 bob kernel: [ 3572.951314] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HD Web Camera (05a3:9331)
Nov 30 19:32:29 bob kernel: [ 3572.977209] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 6 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 1).
Nov 30 19:32:29 bob kernel: [ 3573.003183] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 9 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 1).
Nov 30 19:32:29 bob kernel: [ 3573.029156] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 4 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 1).
Nov 30 19:32:29 bob kernel: [ 3573.049934] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 11 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 1).
Nov 30 19:32:29 bob kernel: [ 3573.076614] uvcvideo 3-1:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
Nov 30 19:32:29 bob kernel: [ 3573.076616] uvcvideo 3-1:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
Nov 30 19:32:29 bob kernel: [ 3573.076716] input: HD Web Camera: HD Web Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input22
Nov 30 19:32:29 bob kernel: [ 3573.078773] usb 3-1: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=3072), cval->res is probably wrong.
Nov 30 19:32:29 bob kernel: [ 3573.078774] usb 3-1: [6] FU [Mic Capture Volume] ch = 1, val = -1536/1536/1
Nov 30 19:32:29 bob kernel: [ 3573.317043] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 6 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 2).
Nov 30 19:32:29 bob kernel: [ 3573.332525] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 6 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 2).
```

Comment: Have you tried with another program? For example `cheese`?

Comment: I have tried using it with Webex from Firefox and I also checked whether the camera is registered as a microphone in KDE's audio settings. Both with the same result: Apparently the camera was not detected before having it connected for a few minutes. I'll try `cheese` as well though.

Comment: Okay I just tried `cheese` and the result is the same.

Comment: There should be log entries when the device is created, could you add them to your question? You connect it and then wait until the device is up and then copy/paste the whole thing. It should be in `/var/log/kern.log`

Comment: @EduardoTrápani "the whole thing" is over 6000 lines long so I ended up only pasting the relevant lines (from the point in time I plugged the camera in). It seems to me that uvcvideo is having some issues (or my camera is a bit stubborn/exotic)...

Comment: Yes, by "the whole thing" I kind of meant what you just added ;). Seeing that log you should consider yourself lucky it works at all. It'd be nice to have the log from the beginning (when you plug it in) until the end (when the device is added), having done a reboot before. Why? Because the module in charge of the webcam could be having issues and because, once you spot how it is recognized/detected, you could feed those values to the module/kernel, so that it doesn't probe so much and it goes straight to the working setup.

Comment: I'll have a look. Thanks for the hint! :)

Comment: Bumping this as I have the exact same issue with the same camera on Ubuntu 20.04 but with Gnome 3.36.8 instead of KDE (but I guess this is not a desktop related issue, but a specific kernel module...)

Comment: @SamBob I just settled with having this delay... I just plug in my webcam like 5 minutes before I actually need it and then it tends to be available on time. However, I didn't notice this delay in recent times anymore. Not sure if somewhere along the lines a kernel update actually fixed the issue... EDIT: Just checked and the kern.log still looks the same, so probably not fixed